# how to copy the dynamic generate source of html in google chrome

Tags: html

In google chrome I have a dynamic generate html code, when I use the inspect html source, the source code did not contain the dynamic html. but when I tried to copy the html in source tab, it only copied the toppest div. what should I do to copy the full nested html code? I have tried all menu but no one work:

[image]

I have tried `copy element` in two levels:

[image]

when I execute the copy element in first div, it only copied one level, when I execute the copy element in second root div level , the copied full nested of html code. I did not know why could this happen. I am using macOS with google chrome 98.

Comment: Copy element should work, or try to update chrome.

Comment: The source code did not contain the dynamic html source, I want to copy the source generate by js dynamic.@FaeemazazBhanej

Comment: The copy element only copied one layer of source , did not copy the full nested source code of html.@FaraazKurawle

Comment: @liangqicai , for me it does, i am using chrome 98 on windows 10